# Pixel Processing Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am looking for some information on pixel processing. I am interested in the following algorithms:

- Gamma correction
- Edge detection
- Changing overall brightness
- Converting to grayscale
- etc.

Where can I find articles that have a description of how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: Codes from my blog. It's turkish but C# is universal :) (http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/c-ile-goruntu-isleme-1/)(http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/c-ile-goruntu-isleme-1/) -
(http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/c-ile-goruntu-isleme-2/)(http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/c-ile-goruntu-isleme-2/) -
(http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/c-ile-goruntu-isleme-3/)(http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/c-ile-goruntu-isleme-3/) -
[Results](http://www.ahmetkakici.com/programlama/goruntu-isleme-ornekleri/)

Comment: And if you need theoretical information check this web site (EN) http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/wksheets.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of these are pretty easy.

A classic book for such things is [Computer Graphics Principles and Practice](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computer-Graphics-Principles-Practice-International/dp/0321210565/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1250756008&sr=8-1).  Its not cheap though.

Wikipedia has some good explanations though

[Gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction)
[Edge Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) though its also worth looking into [highpass filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highpass)

Changing brightness is a bit more subjective and very much connected with gamma correction, imo.

As for grayscale convert .. it can't be easier.  You could just take the average of the r, g & b channels.  However this doesn't correct for the fact that we see green better than other colours.  The "luminance" of an RGB image can be calculated simply by doing (0.3 * r) + (0.59 * g) + (0.11 * b).  As you can see that biases the apparent luminance heavily by green with blue giving far less contribution, which is how our eyes work :)

Answer (score 3):

[Image Processing Fundamentals](http://www.ph.tn.tudelft.nl/Courses/FIP/noframes/fip-Contents.html) is useful to get a theoritical understanding of image processing algorithms.

Also [efg's huge archive](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/ImageProcessing/Algorithms.htm) of links on Image Processing, although some of the links may not work any more.

and [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a good library which implements most image processing algorithms. Here you can find a [good series of tutorials](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut1.html) on it.